# Conversion of TiBlob Object to String

Tags: mobile, camera, titanium, blob, appcelerator-mobile

I need to Convert the TiBlob Image Object to String.I had tried the following Ways.But No Success.

```
var imageFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile('images8.png');
var oneImage = imageFile.read();
var image = oneImage;
var tempFile = Titanium.Filesystem.createTempFile();
tempFile.write(oneImage);
var contents = tempFile.read();
var x = Ti.Utils.base64decode(contents);

alert('type of x is '+typeof(x));  //Object
alert('type of x is '+x.text);   //null
alert(JSON.stringify(oneImage));  //output is null
alert('value of image is '+image);  //TiBlob Object
alert(typeof(contents.toString()));    //String
alert('value of image after conversion is '+contents.toString()); //null
alert('value of text image is '+typeof(contents.text));  //String
alert('value of image after conversion text is '+contents.text);  //null
```

Thanks in Advance...........

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling `Ti.Utils.base64Decode`, you should be calling `Ti.Utils.base64encode`.

Decode converts a *previously* base64 encoded string to a non base64 string.  Encode is what your looking for if you want to pass this image to a server or anything of that nature.

Comment: Try and skip the temp directory stuff and just go straight to `var x = Ti.Utils.base64decode(oneImage);`